# Buscar y reemplazar datos en un array asociativo

Tags: php, array

estoy intentando modificar un campo de un array con los datos de otro con los que va relacionado.

Para que se entienda mejor pongo un ejemplo.

Tengo este array recibido de una bbdd y lo he pasado a json:

```
[
       {
          "codigo": "ALE008",
          "descripcion": "Frutos de cáscara",
          "padre": null,
          "nombrePadre": ""
       },
       {
          "codigo": "AN",
          "descripcion": "Anacardos",
          "padre": "ALE008",
          "nombrePadre": "Frutos de cáscara"
       }
    ]
```

y lo que quiero es pasarlo a este formato:

```
{
   "alergenos": [
        {
         "id": "1",
         "name_ES": "FRUTOS DE CÁSCARA",
         "subalergenos": [
                     {
                      "idsub": "1",
                      "name_es_ES": "Anacardos"
                     }
                 ]
         }
     ]
```

Tengo una función que me almacena a todos los 'padres' en otro array:

```
$alerg=array("alergenos"=>array());
        $array=json_decode($this->get('functions')->enviarAPI('','alergenos'));
        $cont=0;
                foreach ($array as $key => $valor) {
                    foreach($valor as $valor2 =>$valor3){ 

                        if($valor2=='descripcion')$es=$valor3;
                        if($valor2=='nombrePadre' && $valor3==""){
                            $cont=$cont+1;
                            $alerg['alergenos'][]=array(  
                                                          'id'=>$cont,
                                                          "nombre_ES"=> $es,
                                                          'subalergenos'=>''                                   
                                                       ); 
                        }
                    }
                }

               $response = new Response(json_encode($alerg));
               return $response;
```

El problema es que no consigo meter dentro de 'subalergenos' dentro de cada 'padre'.

**Edito con la solución que he encontrado**

Guiándome por la respuesta de Danny he creado lo siguiente:

```
 //recorro el array general
    foreach ($alergenos as $alergeno) {
        if ($alergeno->nombrePadre=="") {
            $subalergenos=$this->obtenerSubalergenos($alergeno->codigo,$alergenos);
            $alergenoPadre=$this->datosAlergeno(1,$alergeno,$subalergenos);
            $alerg['alergenos'][]=$alergenoPadre;
        }
    }
    $response = new Response(json_encode($alerg));
    return $response; 
}

/**
 * Parámetro $tipo=1 para alergenos y 2 para subalergenos
 */

private function datosAlergeno($tipo,$alergeno,$subalergenos) {

    $id=($tipo==1?'id':'idsub');
    $alergenoResult=array(  
        $id=>$alergeno->codigo,
        "nombre_ES"=> $alergeno->descripcion
    );
    if ($tipo==1) $alergenoResult['subalergenos']=$subalergenos;
    return $alergenoResult;
}

private function obtenerSubalergenos($codAlergeno,$arrAlergenos) {
    $arrSubalergenos=array();
    foreach($arrAlergenos as $alergeno) {
        if ($alergeno->padre==$codAlergeno) {
            $arrSubalergenos[]=$this->datosAlergeno(2,$alergeno,null);
        }
    }
    return $arrSubalergenos;
}
```

Bueno, basicamente he optimizado el código llamandolo como objetos y no recorrer el array tantas veces, he creado 2 funciones las cuales datosAlergeno obtiene los datos ya que tanto los hijos como los padres tienen los mismos datos, pero si le paso el codigo 1 creará un array en sus datos donde se introducirán los hijos y si es tipo 2 no creará ese campo.

Esto lo hago para si en un futuro se añaden más idiomas o datos solo lo tienes que cambiar en esa función y aparecerá tanto en padres como hijos.

La segunda función recorre otra vez el array principal y si son hijos los asigno a su padre correspondiente.

Creo que así queda todo mucho más funcional y gracias por la respuestas.

Comment: yo te plantearia que hicieras primero un array con los que son padre. Luego recorres de nuevo el array y si es un hijo, le asignas dentro del padre correspondiente. Pero antes de plantearte codigo, te pregunto: puede haber subalergenos de subalergenos???

Comment: Dentro de los subalergenos no hay más subalergenos. ¿Como podria asignarle el hijo a cada padre que le corresponde?

Comment: Una duda y donde pones "id", "nombre_Es" puedes poner el código tmb, no? Para que puedas saber quien es el padre, porque si no es complicado

Comment: Si se puede poner, aunque la descripción de cada padre siempre coincide con el 'nombrePadre' de los que son hijos por lo que se puede adjudicar al padre por ese campo también

Comment: yo no usaria el nombre. si tiene algun problema (tipo una falta de ortografia, por ej) no coincidiran y no quedara asignado. En su lugar usa el codigo que tienes en PADRE. Si es null es que es un padre, si tiene codigo, ESE codigo es del padre correspondiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una de las cosas que tienes que ver es que los elementos del array son objetos por lo que no hace falta hacer el segundo for, ya que puedes acceder directamente a sus propiedades mediante ->.

He creado una variable hijos, ya que entiendo que alergenos es el padre, y por tanto no tiene sentido meter más complejidad.

Si vemos que el nombre padre es distinto de vació buscamos el elemento en el array de hijos y lo añadimos en el array de subalergenos.

```
$array = json_decode('[
       {
          "codigo": "AN",
          "descripcion": "Anacardos",
          "padre": "ALE008",
          "nombrePadre": "Frutos de cáscara"
       },
       {
          "codigo": "ALE008",
          "descripcion": "Frutos de cáscara",
          "padre": null,
          "nombrePadre": ""
       },
       {
          "codigo": "AN1",
          "descripcion": "PRUEBA",
          "padre": "ALE008",
          "nombrePadre": "Frutos de cáscara"
       }       
    ]');

$hijos = array();
$cont = 0;
foreach ($array as $key => $valor) {

    if ($valor->nombrePadre == ""){
        $cont=$cont+1;
        $hijos[]=array(  
                      'id'=>$cont,
                      "nombre_ES"=> $valor->descripcion,
                      'subalergenos'=> array()                                   
                   );
    }
}
foreach ($array as $key => $valor) {
    if ($valor->nombrePadre != ""){
        foreach ($hijos as $indice => $hijo) {

            if ($hijo["nombre_ES"] == $valor->nombrePadre){
                  $hijos[$indice]["subalergenos"][] = array( "name_es_ES" => $valor->descripcion );
            }
        }
    }
}

$alerg=array("alergenos"=>$hijos);
echo json_encode($alerg);
```

He editado el código teniendo en cuenta lo que comenta Jakala, para ello se recorre dos veces el array uno para encontrar los padres y el segundo para asignar los hijos a los padres.

Comment: solo un apunte: aunque en el ejemplo del json tiene una esctructura, esta viene de bbdd. No es seguro que el primer elemento sea un padre, ni que cuando encuentres un hijo el padre se haya definido anteriormente. Esto haria que tu codigo no funcionara correctamente. (por supuesto, la correccion radica en que la consulta este ordenada primero padres y luego hijos), aunque podrias ordenar el array antes de procesarlo para quitar ese problema

Comment: Buenas, tienes razón yo me guié por el json que él indica y por lo que estaba probando.Aún así sería recorrer el array para encontrar los padres y luego otro bucle for para añadir los hijos y así evitar el problema. No se si modificarlo o dejarlo así la verdad.

Comment: Muchas gracias, el problema es que estaba complicando mucho cuando solo había que buscarlo como objeto,guiándome por tu respuesta he creado dos funciones las cuales una crea un array con todos los padres y luego otro que recorre solo los que son hijos y asignandoselo a cada padre.